# Потоки ввода/вывода С++

Tags: c++

Есть вопрос по потокам ввода/вывода

код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");

    char string[255];
    for (int n = 0; n < size(string); ++n)
    {
        fin >> string[n];
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < size(string) - 1; ++n)
    {
        cout << string[n];
    }
}
```

в файле input.txt лежит текст "Hello world 123" (без кавычек)
на выходе в консоли получаю этот текст и тучу символов непонятных следом.
[image: скрин]

I need help :)

Comment: Так все правильно, а что вы хотели получить?

Comment: У Вас в файле строка в 15 символов, а прочитать Вы пытаетесь 255... Логично, что лишние 240 символов заполнены мусором.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы нигде не проверяете, прочитались символы, или нет. На каждой итерации первого цикла необходимо запрашивать состояние потока и запоминать количество прочитанных символов:

```
size_t const capacity{size(string)}
size_t size{capacity};
for (size_t n{}; n < capacity; ++n)
{
    fin >> string[n];
    if(not fin)
    {
        size = n;
        break;
    }
}

for (size_t n{}; n < size; ++n)
{
    cout << string[n];
}
```